# What does & after a return type mean in C++ OOP

Tags: c++, overloading, pass-by-reference

so I have a method of a class given below that multiplies two complex numbers using operator overloading :

```cpp
Complex operator*(Complex &c2) {
    Complex temp;

    temp.realPart = realPart * c2.realPart - (imaginaryPart * c2.imaginaryPart);
    temp.imaginaryPart = (realPart * c2.imaginaryPart) + (imaginaryPart * c2.realPart);

    return temp;
}
```

This seems to work fine. However, my program does not run when I change the member function header to:

```cpp
Complex& operator * (Complex &c2) {  // Adding & after the class name.
```

The program does not crash but it can't compute the answer/ ends after the cursor on the program blinks for a while. What does & after the class name mean? And I have seen it being used when returning a this pointer.

Comment: The return type is a reference to the object.

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local variable.  A reference is syntactic sugar for an auto-dereferenced pointer.  Under the covers you're returning a pointer to an object that gets de-allocated when the method returns.

Comment: `operator*` is expected to return a new object, so returning a reference is just wrong. Also, the input parameter should be passed in by `const` reference: `Complex operator*(const Complex &c2)`

Comment: Realize that the original works because you are returning a *copy* of `temp`, not `temp` itself, while the reference version is returning a *reference* to `temp`, which was on the stack inside the method.  But after the return, `temp` no longer exists.  The caller to this operator overload has a reference to something that no longer exists, hence the strange undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> What does & after a return type mean in C++

It means the same thing as & after any type. It means that the type is a reference. So, if it is after a return type, then it means that the function returns a reference.

Your function returns an automatic variable. Returning a reference to an automatic variable is useless, because the automatic object is destroyed upon returning, so the reference becomes invalid immediately.

If you attempt to access the non-existing object through the returned invalid reference, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your Are Returning a Refrence To An Object just like next to any variable , Now that is good in some cases, but in others you might be returning a refrence to temporary variables and then by any change these temporary objects get freed from memory then you are referencing a freed block of memory
The Cherno explains it very well in his rvalue and lvalues video you can go and see it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbYknr-HPYE